# These parse query not working properly in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform, pfquery

I am checking two conditions with parse in iOS. In parse I have mainly 2 keys in class (class name `app`) and keys are `uuid` and `expiryDate`.

- 1. Check user unique id (uuid) is available in parse or not.
- 2. Check  `expiryDate` field corresponding to that uuid is greater than current date and time in GMT.

But when I try the below query it checking only first condition
second date checking is not happening.

**Code**

```
    NSString *udid = [[UIDevice currentDevice] uniqueDeviceIdentifier];

    NSDate *currentDate = [NSDate new];
    NSDate *localDate = currentDate; // get the date

    NSTimeInterval timeZoneOffset = [[NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone] secondsFromGMT]; // You could also use the systemTimeZone method

    NSTimeInterval gmtTimeInterval = [localDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate] - timeZoneOffset;

    NSDate *gmtDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceReferenceDate:gmtTimeInterval];

    PFQuery *wawQuery = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"app"];
    [wawQuery whereKey:@"udid" equalTo:udid];  
    [wawQuery whereKey:@"expiryDate" greaterThan:gmtDate]; //checking not working

    [wawQuery findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *users, NSError *error) {


    NSLog(@"user-->%@",[[users valueForKey:@"expiryDate"] objectAtIndex:0]);
    NSDate *serverDate=(NSDate *)[[users valueForKey:@"expiryDate"] objectAtIndex:0];
    if([users count]>0){
        if([gmtDate compare:serverDate]==NSOrderedAscending){
            NSLog(@"not expired");
            sharedManager.status=true;
            liveController *rxObj= [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"live"];
            [self.navigationController pushViewController:rxObj animated:YES];

        }else{
            NSLog(@"expired");
            sharedManager.status=false;
            [self initiateControlls];
        }


    }else{
        sharedManager.status=false;
         [self initiateControlls];
    }
```

I am expecting a date check like this

for eg 19-04-2015 21:20:00   and 19-04-2015 22:00:04   but

when I use

```
if([gmtDate compare:serverDate]==NSOrderedAscending){

   }
```

only date is checking (19-04-2015 to 19-04-2015 22:00:04) and I want both date time check  (19-04-2015 21:20:00 to 19-04-2015)

Comment: Be more specific about your problem. What's not happening about it?

Comment: right  now only date part is checking its not taking care of time

Comment: updated my question code

Comment: You have to use NSDateFormatter to get it in the format you want. Plenty of tutorials out there

Answer (score 0):

This link might be helpful for your condition:

https://www.parse.com/questions/comparing-dates-with-the-ios-sdk